# function not setting cookie till after the index runs

Tags: php, function, return

So I have a php function that is used in a few different pages. To cut down on code, I made functions.php page to be called.

so my index calls functionX, and in that function it sets cookies. But I have the function in a IF statement, it seems to set the cookie, but not till all the code on index runs....

Here an an example code. the code should return "whatever", but instead it returns null

index.php:

```
 require_once('functions.php');
 $cookie = ''; //just doing this to assume the cookie is always null.

 if ($cookie == '') {
    functionX();
$cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie']['random'];
 }

 echo ''.$cookie; //returns null.......
```

functions.php:

```
 function functionX() {
 $randomvar = 'whatever';
 setcookie("cookie[random]", $randomvar, time()+60*60*24*30, "/", "www.myweburl.com", 0, true);
 }
```

now I would think it would run through the entire function BEFORE continuing on, but it doesn't seem that way...

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` is created before your code is processed just like $_POST and $_GET. If you initiate the cookie after page load it will be empty. What you can do is this:

```
$cookie = functionX('random');

function functionX($key) {
   if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'][$key]) {
       return $_COOKIE['cookie'][$key];
   } else {
       $randomvar = 'whatever';
       setcookie("cookie[$key]", $randomvar, time()+60*60*24*30, "/", "www.myweburl.com", 0, true);
       return $randomvar;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is intended if you look at the [setcookie() docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) you will note the sentences `Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load` and `setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers` and resulting of this your set cookie is not set in the current session already.

What you could do is modify the global array holding the cookies so they seem to be present in the current session. Basically the following way:

```
function functionX() {
  $randomvar = 'whatever';
  setcookie("cookie[random]", $randomvar, time()+60*60*24*30, "/", "www.myweburl.com", 0, true);
  $_COOKIE['cookie']['random'] = $randomvar;
}
```